# Is there a way to capture table level edits in postgres using debezium?

Tags: postgresql, etl, debezium

I am using postgres, kafka and debizium for capturing the changes that are happening to rows in the tables to build an ETL pipeline

Can someone please let me know how we can capture updates like adding/deleting a new column or changing the default value of a column etc?

I have tried adding/deleting columns but no events are being captured by debezium.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Logical decoding does not (yet) support DDL statements like `CREATE`, `ALTER` and `DROP`, so there is no way you can get that.

Comment: Then how can I create the warehouse tables schema after changes has been done in source tables? Let's say a new column is added with integer datatype, we would have to create similar column in the destination table as well

Comment: This is also part of the question
`Can someone please let me know how we can capture updates like adding/deleting a new column or changing the default value of a column etc?`

Comment: Well, I answered it: "there is no way you can get that". Nada, nothing, basta.